# using rot13 and tr command for having an encrypted email address

Tags: shell

I have read many tutorials on the internet about the usage of the 'tr' command.
However, I am not able to understand how to encrypt an email address with a shell script shift the characters using rot13. Can any one give a link or an example?

Comment: "tr" command tutorial on wikipedia. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tr_%28Unix%29

Answer (score 143, accepted):

Not sure exactly how you want to use this, but here's a basic example to get you started:

```
echo 'fooman@example.com' | tr 'A-Za-z' 'N-ZA-Mn-za-m'
```

To make it easier, you can alias the `tr` command in your `.bashrc` file thusly:

```
alias rot13="tr 'A-Za-z' 'N-ZA-Mn-za-m'"
```

Now you can just call:

```
echo 'fooman@example.com' | rot13
```

Comment: is it necessary to use a-z as SET 1 and n-za-m in set2 can it be used in some other way? I mean a-z p-z-a-q set2

Comment: Any other combination wouldn't be rot **13**  ;-)

Comment: Additionally, if you want to rot13 the digits (which isn't traditional rot13, because that's only the letters), you can add 0-9 to SET1 and 3-90-2 to SET2.

Comment: @xizdaqrian That wouldn't be self-inverse --- maybe from 0-9 to 5-90-4 would be more in the spirit of rot13?

Answer (score 26):

A perfect task for `tr`, indeed.  This should do what you want:

```
tr 'A-Za-z' 'N-ZA-Mn-za-m'
```

Each character in the first set will be replaced with the corresponding character in the second set.  E.g. A replaced with N, B replaced with O, etc..  And then the same for the lower case letters.  All other characters will be passed through unchanged.

**Note the lack of `[` and `]` where you normally might expect them.**  This is because `tr` treats square brackets literally, not as range expressions.  So, for example, `tr -d '[A-Z]'` will delete capital letters *and* square brackets.  If you wanted to keep your brackets, use `tr -d 'A-Z'`:

```
$ echo "foo BAR [baz]" | tr -d '[A-Z]'
foo  baz
$ echo "foo BAR [baz]" | tr -d 'A-Z'
foo  [baz]
```

Same for character classes.  E.g. `tr -d '[[:lower:]]'` is probably an error, and should be `tr -d '[:lower:]'`.

However, in lucky situations like this one, you can get away with including the brackets anyway!  For example, `tr "[a-z]" "[A-Z]"` accidentally works because the square brackets in the first set are replaced by identical square brackets from the second set, but really this is a bad habit to get into.  Use `tr "a-z" "A-Z"` instead.

Answer (score 10):

Ruby(1.9+)

```
$ ruby -ne 'print $_.tr( "A-Za-z", "N-ZA-Mn-za-m") ' file
```

Python

```
$ echo "test" | python -c 'import sys; print sys.stdin.read().encode("rot13")'
```

Comment: Python example is Python 2 only.  Python 3 got more strict about binary strings vs unicode strings, and 'rot13' is a rare example of string-to-string "codec".

Answer (score 10):

to simultaneously do ROT13 (for letters) and ROT5 (for numbers):

```
tr 'A-Za-z0-9' 'N-ZA-Mn-za-m5-90-4'
```

usage:

```
echo test | tr 'A-Za-z0-9' 'N-ZA-Mn-za-m5-90-4'
```

alias definition for your `~/.bashrc` in case you need it more often:

```
alias rot="tr 'A-Za-z0-9' 'N-ZA-Mn-za-m5-90-4'"
```

(accurately rot135 or rot18)

Answer (score 6):

**# Reciprocal Transformation(s)**

```
# rot13
tr 'A-Za-z' 'N-ZA-Mn-za-m' <<< 'user@domain.com'

# rot13.5 (rot18)
tr 'A-Za-z0-9' 'N-ZA-Mn-za-m5-90-4' <<< 'user123@domain.com'

# rot47
tr '\!-~' 'P-~\!-O' <<< 'user123@domain.com'

# rot13 -- SED anyone
echo 'user@domain.com' | sed y/NOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklm/ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz/
```

**Shell Script**

```
#!/bin/bash
# Purpose: Rotate 13 characters (a reciprocal transformation)

# ./rot13.sh 'A String to look Ciphered'
tr 'A-Za-z' 'N-ZA-Mn-za-m' <<< "$1"

exit $?
```

Comment: `man tr` command if you have GNU coreutils, or http://man.jimmylandstudios.xyz/?man=tr

Answer (score 1):

#### You can execute it inside a shell script

```
#!/bin/bash
echo 'rot13@rot.com' | tr 'A-Za-z' 'N-ZA-Mn-za-m'

echo 'rot13@rot.com' | rot13
```

#### Make the file executable by running:

```
sudo chmod +x file_name
```

#### To ouput the answer run:

```
./file_name
example:
./try.sh
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).