# How can I create a menu in Linux that can decrypt and encrypt a file using ROT13?

Tags: linux, bash, unix

```
#!/bin/bash

    selection=
    until [ "$selection" = "0"]; do
     echo ""
     echo "PROGRAM MENU"
     echo "1 - Encrypt text with Rot13"
     echo "2 - DEcrypt text with Rot13"
     echo ""
     echo "0 - Exit program"
     echo ""
     echo -n "Enter Selection:"
     read selection
     echo ""
     case $selection in
         1 ) echo "Line to be encrypted"
         rot13 "a-z"
         2 ) echo "Line to be decrypted"
         rot13 "n-za-m"
         3 ) exit;;
         * ) echo "Please enter 1,2, or 0"
     esac
done
```

I want to read a .txt file, encrypt it, save it, and afterwards decrypt it.

Comment: You do realize that encrypting and decrypting with Rot13 are the same operation, right?

Answer (score 2):

A quick google search for "rot13 in bash" gave this: [using rot13 and tr command for having an encrypted email address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5442436/using-rot13-and-tr-command-for-having-an-encrypted-email-address)

In short:

```
echo 'fooman@example.com' | tr '[A-Za-z]' '[N-ZA-Mn-za-m]'
```

This should ROT13 fooman@example.com.  From here its easy enough to add a menu item, feed tr a file instead of piping it, and save the output to a file.  All those other operations are also easily found by a quick search.